# Reference for ECMAJavascript Library gets?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

Is there a method reference for all the gets/sets in the. ECMAScript JavaScript library for sharepoint 2010. I know the obvious answer is MSDN but I have trouble finding anything there. For example I found the JavaScript Library and under SP Namespace I found User....but I am looking for what I can use ( get_title, get_id, get_email...etc) but the only thing there is email. I know there are more more gets than that so I think I just don't understand the structure or how to navigate it....alas does anyone know where I can find a good reference for all the gets and such.

Appreciate it as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to check the class it inherits from, the SP.User Class inherits from the SP.Principal Class.

There you find properties like:

- id
- loginName
- principalType
- title

Another options is to check the properties of the object.

Example:

```
function runCode() {

     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
     user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();  
     clientContext.load(user);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    for(var prop in user)
    {
        console.log(prop);
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks once more Anders.... This helps tremendously! Appreciated

Comment: This is great, I was having the same problem today with correlating the official MS docs (which give you the C# methods) to the actual SP.JS get_xxxx methods.